# Kiddush for a latecomer

Tags: kiddush

If someone already made Kiddush on Friday night and now someone came late to the meal and asked him to make Kiddush again, but the latecomer refuses to drink from the wine, is it permitted for the one making Kiddush to recite the blessing over the wine (borei pri hagefen) even though the Kiddush maker doesn’t need the blessing as he already made it a few minutes earlier and the latecomer won’t be using it either?

Would this be the same or different on Kiddush by Shabbos day?

Comment: Are you permitted to do kiddush twice?

Comment: Friday night Kiddush can be made over bread, if the latecomer is amenable to that.

Comment: @Kazi with all blessings on Mitzvot the rule is Yatza Motzi - one who already fulfilled his obligation can still say it for others.

Comment: @DoubleAA That is why I was asking it. I suppose it's a non-trivial condition that should be edited in.

Comment: I don't see this idea as any different from other *motzi acherim* mitzvoth such as blowing shofar or reading megilla multiple times so that he can fulfill others' obligations. I think in this case, you need to separate the mitzvah of Kiddush from the drinking of the wine itself. Is your question focusing on *bracha she'eino tzricha*, because that's what I'm inferring. If so, I don't think that concern applies, here, as the bracha on the wine is needed for the Kiddush.